# Check multiple matches from column A with multiple matches in column B

Tags: sql

I have two columns.

Column A is IP source addresses.
Column B is the respective domain query.

Example table as follows:

[table link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkgjI.png)

How do I check if there are multiple IP addresses querying the same group of domains?

So the result would in theory show List 1 of IP addresses have all queried list 2 of domains

I would like to somehow present all results for the whole initial table

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post sample data and expected output (as text)!

Comment: (Padme meme) as text, right?